# DXA in the Microsoft Azure marketplace - Content services are not responding, Is it still supported?

Tags: dxa, azure

I was following along with Bart Koopman's article
[**DXA in the Microsoft Azure Marketplace**](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-in-the-microsoft-azure-marketplace#), to create a DXA.Net sample but

The freshly created WebApp DXA.log shows

> 2017-10-26 16:05:33,329 [7] INFO  - Still unable to resolve Localization after 11 seconds...
>
> 2017-10-26 16:05:34,236 [9] ERROR - An error occured while
> communicating with
>
> https://cm-web-61f5df-dev-eu-west-1-azuredemo.tridion.sdlproducts.com
>
> 2017-10-26 16:05:43,288 [7] INFO  - Still unable to resolve Localization after 12 seconds...
>
> ......
>
> 2017-10-26 16:07:42,073 [7] INFO  - Still unable to resolve Localization after 28 seconds...

The site returns 500 - The request timed out.

Is the Azure market place DXA.Net Demo still supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some problems with the CIS backend used for Azure DXA and an unclear support status which is being addressed.

At the point of writing the service is back online again, and we are monitoring it more closely so hopefully it stays available.